# Wrapping/intercepting a promise in an inner function

Tags: node.js, promise, wrapper

I'm having difficulty finding an answer to my question, perhaps because I don't know how to ask it (what search terms to use). I'm really struggling to understand promises, and have watched a number of tutorial videos and am still not getting some fundamental piece to make it click.

In Node, I am using the request-promise module, which returns a promise when I make a call to an rp() method. I am calling 
    return rp(service);
from within a function. But what I want to do, instead, is add a .then() handler to this to do some post-processing with the result of the service call, BEFORE returning the promise back to the caller so the caller can still have its own then handler.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe you could show us some of your code?

Comment: `return rp(service).then(…)`? Notice the `then` returns another promise for the result of the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to see your current code to better understand where exactly you are struggling with.

In general, you can think of promises as a placeholder for some future value that you can chain together.

If I understood your question correctly, you would like to make a request to a server, receive the response, do something with the response and return it back to the caller.

```
const callService = (url) => {
  // make sure to return your promise here
  return rp(url)
    .then((html) => {
       // do something with html
       return html;
     });
};
```

Now you can call it like so -

```
callService('http://www.google.com')
  .then((html) => {
     console.log(html);
  }).catch((err) => {
    // error handling
  });
```

The common mistake is to omit the return statement in your top level function and subsequent then functions.

Feel free to provide additional details.

Comment: Thanks - that was what I was trying to do. I didn't realize it was just that easy to tack on a .then where I was doing return rp(url). This just works. :)

Comment: @user1588877 No problem! It takes a bit to get used to it, but once you get the hang of it, it's so much nicer than callbacks. Just make sure you always return in between and at the top level. Try async/await next!